# 2 monitors, pygame.display.Info won't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have two monitors (one is 1920x1080, the other is 1024x768) and I've just started a new game and ran into an issue with `pg.display.Info`:

```
import pygame as pg
pg.init()
x,y = pg.display.Info()
```

It gives me the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\marty\Desktop\New Text Document (2).py", line 3, in 
>       x,y = pg.display.Info()
>   TypeError: 'VidInfo' object is not iterable

Even after isolating the code to those three lines, the same error gets raised. I couldn't find any info on 2 monitors in Python.

PS: pygame is updated, according to pip. My Python version is 3.6.5, and I'm running windows 10.

Comment: `pg.display.Info()` returns a `VidInfo` object/class, you should pull the attribute out that you want, instead of trying to unpack it

Comment: sorry, i don't understand, mind giving an example?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? If you want to open two windows: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8107070/6220679

Comment: i was trying to get the monitor's size. i'd also want to know how to specify which monitor to check, but i don't need to know. sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't unpack the `VidInfo` object which [`pg.display.Info()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.Info) returns like that. Assign it to a single variable and then use the attributes that you need. For example:

```
info = pg.display.Info()
print(info)
print(info.current_w, info.current_h)
```

Comment: Thanks! works for me. also, would there be a way to get the seccond monitor's size?

Comment: I don't know if there's a way.