# pygame fullscreen on second monitor

Tags: python, pygame, sdl

I am trying to have my pygame window open on my second monitor. Executing

```py
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size, HWSURFACE | DOUBLEBUF | FULLSCREEN)
```

always opens the window on the first monitor. I did manage to get the game running on 2nd monitor with borderless windowed with the following:

```py
display_info = py.display.Info()
size = width, height = display_info.current_w, display_info.current_h
os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS'] = str(width) + ",0"
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size, HWSURFACE | DOUBLEBUF | NOFRAME)
```

Is there a similar workaround for fullscreen?

Comment: Related [pygame dual monitors and fullscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7097163/pygame-dual-monitors-and-fullscreen/8107070), [Pygame choose which display to use in fullscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34526835/pygame-choose-which-display-to-use-in-fullscreen)

Comment: A really great answer to this question would work cross-platform too.